# flutter convert get value string to double google map

Tags: flutter

I want to convert a value from String to double for fetching data in google map but it says The instance member 'lat','lag' can't be accessed in an initializer.

```
String lat = '${searchitems[0].address![widget.index].latitude}';
double latitude = double.parse(lat);

 String lng = '${searchitems[0].address![widget.index].longitude}';
 double longitude = double.parse(lng);


 static const LatLng centerMap =
  LatLng(lat, lng);  <<<<<<<< I want to get the value to put here.
```

This is code textformfield where i will pull to googlemap get value from longitude page

```
TextFormField(
            initialValue:
                '${searchitems[0].address![widget.index].longitude}'
                    .replaceAll(badNull[0], ''),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'longitude',
              labelStyle:
                  TextStyle(fontFamily: 'supermarket', fontSize: 16),
              isDense: true,
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: It looks like you are setting the String variables to strings when they are objects yours trying to get data from. Have you tried removing the single quotes and doing a .toString?

Comment: Can you share more of your code? Would be helpfull to know if this happens in a widget or a function...

Comment: Is it `lag` or `lng`?

Comment: Pl also share the error log.

Comment: It shouldn't be static. If it should be, it shouldn't be then it shouldn't depend on instance fields (lat and lng)